# Runtime Error C++ USACO Training - " Run 1: Execution error: Your program had this runtime error:Illegal file open (gift1.out). "

Tags: c++, file, runtime-error

I've been attempting the USACO training page problems and have been receiving a runtime error that says " Run 1: Execution error: Your program had this runtime error:
Illegal file open (gift1.out). The program ran for 0.004 CPU
seconds before the error. It used 1336 KB of memory. "
Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream outfile ("gift1.out");
  ofstream fout ("gift1.out");
  ifstream fin ("gift1.in");
  int numPeople;
  string currentGiver;
  string currentRec;
  int perPerson;
  int forGiver;
  fin >> numPeople;
  string name[numPeople];
  float amount[numPeople];
  float recNum[numPeople];
  int money[numPeople];
  for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++){
    fin >> name[i];
    money[i] = 0;
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < numPeople; j++){
    fin >> currentGiver;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++){
      if (currentGiver == name[i]){
        fin >> amount[i];
        fin >> recNum[i];
        perPerson = amount[i]/recNum[i];
        forGiver = amount[i] - (perPerson * recNum[i]);
        money[i] += forGiver;
        money[i] -= amount[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < recNum[i]; k++){
          fin >> currentRec;
          for (int m = 0; m < numPeople; m++){
            if (currentRec == name[m]){
              money[m] += (perPerson);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }   
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++){
    fout << name[i] << " " <<money[i] << endl;   
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the first couple of lines from the file called gift1.out which should in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Why did you open the output file twice?